# In has_many through is there a way to reference the join table directly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Can you reference the properties of a join table in a `has_many :through` relationship?

**Classic join relationship:**

```
class Committee
  has_many :positions
  has_many :members, through: :positions
end

class Member
  has_many :positions
end

class Positions
  belongs_to :committee
  belongs_to :member

  attr_accessible :description
end
```

This gives us a nice way to access members directly from the Committee:

```
c = Factory :committee
first_member = members.first
```

**Accessing information on the join table via the association**

Is there some way to reference the description of the position (which exists on the join table) from this relationship?

e.g.

```
first_member_description = members.first.proxy.description
```

If not then what's the cleanest way to access the description of a particular *committee member*?

**Why would I want to do this?**

I want to do this because I want to find a committee member by name and then find their description:

i.e.

```
peters_description = committee.members.find_by_first_name('Peter').proxy.description
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add the finder on the Position class:

```
class Position < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :committee
  belongs_to :member

  attr_accessible :description

  scope :find_all_by_first_name, lambda do |name|
    joins(:member).where("members.first_name = ?", name)
  end
end
```

This should allow you to do:

```
peters_description = committee.positions.find_all_by_first_name('Peter').first.description
```

Comment: This ended up being more or less the solution I ended up going with - I had only tried to avoid it previously to minimise hits to the database but I'm not sure there's a good alternative